# Docker - check if postgres is ready

Tags: postgresql, docker, centos, kong

I have a [Kong API Gateway](https://hub.docker.com/_/kong/) container and a [postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) container and I need to check whether postgres has started up and ready from the Kong container before running the migrations. I was thinking of installing the postgres client utilities into a custom image based on the official Kong image using `RUN yum install postgresql -y && yum clean all` in my Dockerfile and using either `psql` or `pg_isready` to achieve this. I've created a postgres user called `polling` with an empty password specifically for checking the status of the server by these two utilities. Neither of them work.

I tried to execute these commands from the custom Kong image:

1. **psql**. The command `psql -h postgres -U polling -w -c '\l'` fails with the error `psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`. But the user has no password. What am I doing wrong? The full shell script checking whether the server is ready using psql is described [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/).
2. **pg_isready**. I don't get how to install this utility separately into a custom image based on the official Kong image which in turn based on the `centos:7` image, the `postgresql` package doesn't include `pg_isready`. Only these utilities are installed and can be found in `/usr/bin`: `pg_config`, `pg_dump`, `pg_dumpall`, `pg_restore`, `psql`. How to install `pg_isready`? I don't want to have the full server installation in the Kong image.

Comment: Regarding #1, have you adjusted the pg_hba.conf? See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83164/remove-password-requirement-for-user-postgres

Comment: @bluescores right, I need to change this config or add .pgpass on the client. Solved the issue with the latter. I should notice that I had to set a password for my polling user, psql shouted at me if the pass was empty regardless .pgpass

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My solution was to create a new image based on the official kong image and override the entrypoint like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

# Disabling nginx daemon mode
export KONG_NGINX_DAEMON="off"

# Setting default prefix (override any existing variable)
export KONG_PREFIX="/usr/local/kong"

# Prepare Kong prefix
if [ "$1" = "/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx" ]; then
    kong prepare -p "/usr/local/kong"
fi

#waiting for postgres
until psql --host=$KONG_PG_HOST --username=$POLLING_USER $POLLING_DATABASE -w &>/dev/null
do
  echo "Waiting for PostgreSQL..."
  sleep 1
done

echo "Postgres is ready, running the migrations..."

kong migrations up

echo "READY TO START UP KONG USING CMD" $@;

exec "$@"
```

Answer (score 72):

Here is a shell one liner using `pg_isready` tool provided by PostgreSQL.

To call outside docker:

```sh
DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME="mypgcontainer"
timeout 90s bash -c "until docker exec $DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME pg_isready ; do sleep 5 ; done"
```

[Based on a post from Jeroma Belleman](http://jeromebelleman.gitlab.io/posts/devops/until/).

Comment: I am surprised this answer doesn't get more upvotes. I came to the same conclusion, it really works with `pg_isready` while doesn't work with the "wait for-it.sh" bash script as the TCP port is ready before postgres is really ready to "work". Otherwise, you can get errors like: `An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] server closed the connection unexpectedly`.

Comment: It is a new answer.

Answer (score 23):

I tried wait-for-it, but it may be a problem to run it in docker container as in the docker image may not be installed nc (sometimes there is not even ping, telnet, curl..). So to check if the DB is up and running I have used HealthCheck in docker compose file what was checking return value of pg_isready, what is part of postgres database, so you do not need to install anything into docker images:

```
version: '2.3'
services:
  postgres-db:
    image: postgresImage
    healthcheck:
      test: /usr/bin/pg_isready
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

  aplication:
    image: applicationImage
    depends_on:
      postgres-db:
        condition: service_healthy
```

Comment: depends_on is removed in compose v3

Comment: @super.t `depends_on` is [still around](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) in v3.

Comment: @MikeBranski [Version 3 no longer supports the condition form of depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on)

Comment: @MikeBranski @davidgoli @super.t To add to the confusion, Docker-Compose v3.9 re-added `condition` for `depends_on`. You can now control startup via `service_started`, `service_healthy` and `service_completed_successfully` conditions.

Comment: Thanks. For what it's worth, on `postgres:alpine`, `ps_isready` isn't in `/usr/bin`, and I had to specify user and db. `test: ps_isready -d ${DB_NAME} -U ${DB_USERNAME}` worked fine.

Answer (score 8):

We solve this with a simple TCP check on port 5432, without any PG tooling. We just use `wait-for-it.sh`, and it works well. Postgres does not open the port until the server is actually ready to serve, so this is apparently fine.

Sample Dockerfile: https://github.com/apim-haufe-io/wicked.kong/blob/master/Dockerfile

Corresponding start script (only the last line is interesting for this specific problem): https://github.com/apim-haufe-io/wicked.kong/blob/master/startup.sh

Snippet:

```
wait-for-it.sh -h $KONG_PG_HOST -p 5432 -t 30 -- kong start --run-migrations
```

Wait for it: https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it

Comment: this doesn't work when you have to launch postgres in a container for the first time as the server will be ready and attempting to run the start up scripts. I've had requests to the server cause the init script to crash sadly.

Comment: Agree with @jemiloii. The port is available earlier than the Postgres is ready to run scripts

Comment: I have also seen this once in a while, but not that common. In some places, I have also seen `sleep 5` after wait-for-it has returned, and that is typically enough. Belt and suspenders would call for runnint wait-for-it, sleep, wait-for-it. Typically good enough for me.

Comment: wait-for-it.sh timeout does not work on mac.

Answer (score 1):

As several answers mention, using `pg_isready` is a great way to do this.

HOWEVER, if your image may be loading data or doing other initialisation work through scripts in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`, then this test will succeed during that phase, even when the DB isn't really "ready".

To avoid this, add `-h localhost` to the `pg_isready` invocation.  During the initialisation process, postgres is ONLY available via UNIX sockets, so the test will fail until the server is brought down and restarted in a "production" configuration that includes TCP access.

Example snipped from a `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: pguser
  postgres:
    healthcheck:
      # The `-h localhost` is a MUST, else we'll pass the health test during initialisation
      test: pg_isready -h localhost -U $$POSTGRES_USER
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 15
```

Comment: Can you give a short example on how to do this, my approach is at the moment: 
'HEALTHCHECK --interval=60s --timeout=30s --start-period=5s --retries=10 CMD [ "-h localhost", "pg_isready" ]' in the Dockerfile itself, which does not work.

Comment: @JKupzig: Added an example that I've been using.  I've only discovered very recently that the HEALTHCHECK can actually be done in the Dockerfile itself.  I've not experimented with that yet.

Comment: Thanks! Using the docker compose would not Work because we want to use the Image in several projects. My Solution was to write a healthcheck.sh which checks if a file that is created After the upload of the dump exists.