# flask app service can't connect to postgres service within docker-compose

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, startup-probe

I am trying to run flask, postgres and nginx services with following docker-compose:

```
version: '3.6'


services:

  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.5
    container_name: postgres
    hostname: postgres
    user: postgres  
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - db-tier
    environment:
      CUSTOM_CONFIG: /etc/postgres/postgresql.conf
    volumes:
      - ./postgres/sql/create_tables.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
      - ./postgres/postgresql.conf:/etc/postgres/postgresql.conf
    command: postgres -c config_file=/etc/postgres/postgresql.conf
    restart: always

  app:
    image: python/app:0.0.1
    container_name: app
    hostname: app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
     - postgres
    networks:
      - app-tier
      - db-tier
    stdin_open: true

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.22
    container_name: nginx-reverse-proxy-flask
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - app
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    networks:
      - app-tier


networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge
  db-tier:
    driver: bridge
```

This is what `app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]` equals to     `postgresql://denis:1234Five@postgres:5432/app`

The error after docker-compose up is:

```
app         | psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
app         |   Is the server running on host "postgres" (192.168.32.2) and accepting
app         |   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

What could cause this type of error? I double checked the container name of postgres service, and it running with this name `postgres` why flask app doesn't "see" it?

Comment: Try to start only postgress and connect to it via exec or attach

Comment: @RyabchenkoAlexander with command  docker run --rm -it -p 5555:5555 --entrypoint=sh python/app:0.0.1, but i can't get why it doesn't work inside docker networks

Comment: maybe problem is caused by fact taht you have 2 networks

Comment: @RyabchenkoAlexander didn't found out the reason why depends_on doesn't work, I found the solution to firstly run postgres service with `docker-compose up -d postgres` and the within `docker-compose up` to run the rest ones

Comment: may be problem with no pg startup probe 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516584/docker-check-if-postgres-is-ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved with postgres `pg_isready` adding following lines to `postgres` service:

```
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD-SHELL", "sh -c 'pg_isready -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -d ${POSTGRES_DB}'"]
  interval: 10s
  timeout: 3s
  retries: 3
```

Took as solution from here [Safe ways to specify postgres parameters for healthchecks in docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65115627/safe-ways-to-specify-postgres-parameters-for-healthchecks-in-docker-compose)

Answer (score 1):

It could be issue with no propper startup probe in your postgres container and docker-compose.yml
Look at for reference how to setup them at [Docker - check if postgres is ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516584/docker-check-if-postgres-is-ready)

So after postgres starts as container, docker starts your app, but postgres inside of container is not ready yet and you get your error